# Copy entire SQL Database via C#'s SqlConnection

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlconnection

I have two connection strings, the first is to an existing database, and the second is to a different SQL Server. I need to copy the entire first database to the second one. This includes creating all the tables, constraints, and keys. I want to use the `SqlConnection` object and do not have access to a hard drive.

EDIT 1:
I can create the db (code below) but I can't figure out how to programmatically set up the tables and then populate them. What is the best way to approach this?

```
public void Copy()
{
    var connectionForExisting = "REDACTED";
    var connectionForNew = "REDACTED";
    var targetDbName = "REDACTED";

    var source = new SqlConnection(connectionForExisting);
    var target = new SqlConnection(connectionForNew);

    try
    {
        source.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        source.Close();
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        target.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        source.Close();
        target.Close();
        return;
    }

    var myCommand = new SqlCommand(String.Format(CreateNewDatabaseScript, targetDbName), target);
    try
    {
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        source.Close();
        target.Close();
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why would you want to do it this way, instead of for example restoring a backup into the second server?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis I apparently, derped. I edited the O.P. to include the question.

Comment: @JamesZ I need to do it programmatically and I don't have access to any disk space. Is there a way to back up and restore that fits both of these criteria?

Comment: I assumed you had backups of your database that you could just restore. You could also use replication to copy the database. Building this yourself sounds like a big task, depending of course how many objects and how much data you have.

Comment: Do you need to copy data or just copy the database's schema?

Comment: @JamesZ Yeah, I don't know what the best approach is. This was my attempt at starting it. And yes, there are a LOT of objects and data.

Comment: @IlyaChumakov Both, but I could do it in two steps if that helps.

Comment: @JamesMadison, If you have no possibility to place *.bak file on remote machine (probably it's a simplest way to restore db programmaticaly), try SMO and `Transfer` class http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268381/using-smo-to-copy-a-database-and-data